# how to make allied vision camera object a global variable?

Tags: python

I use allied vision camera, I need to get single frame very frequently, but I found it needs more than 1 sec to find the camera and get single frame. Please look at this code (edited from [pymba](https://github.com/morefigs/pymba/blob/master/examples/camera/opencv_acquire_image.py))

```
from pymba import Vimba, VimbaException
from examples.camera._display_frame import display_frame
def capture_single():
    with Vimba() as vimba:
         camera = vimba.camera(0)
         camera.open()
         camera.arm('SingleFrame')
         for i in range(10):
             try:
                 frame = camera.acquire_frame()
                 print(frame)
            
             except VimbaException as e:
                 # rearm camera upon frame timeout
                 if e.error_code == VimbaException.ERR_TIMEOUT:
                    print(e)
                    camera.disarm()
                    camera.arm('SingleFrame')
                 else:
                    raise
    camera.disarm()
    camera.close()
    return frame


   
  if __name__ == '__main__':                     
    for i in range(10):
        frame = capture_single()
```

here in main body the first loop is very slow, but the loop in the function capture_single() is very fast. so how could I make `camera = vimba.camera(0)` as a global variable, so in my own program, anytime if I want to get frame in different functions I just directly use  `frame = camera.acquire_frame()` quickly instead of finding the camera and open the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could either declare the variable outside of the method or create a class that wraps this behavior (the latter is usually preferred).

If this is just a one-off script that doesn't really have many components outside of taking the single shot, you could simply use

```
with Vimba() as vimba:
    # Not sure if you have to call camera.open() or arm() in every frame. If so, move it accordingly.
    camera = vimba.camera(0)
    camera.open()
    camera.arm('SingleFrame')

def capture_single():
     for i in range(10):
         try:
             frame = camera.acquire_frame()
             print(frame)
            
         except VimbaException as e:
             # rearm camera upon frame timeout
             if e.error_code == VimbaException.ERR_TIMEOUT:
                print(e)
                camera.disarm()
                camera.arm('SingleFrame')
             else:
                raise
    camera.disarm()
    camera.close()
    return frame
```

Otherwise, it may be best to define a class to wrap this, i.e.

```
class CameraInteractor:
    def __init__(self):
        with Vimba() as vimba:
            self.camera = vimba.camera(0)
            self.camera.open()
            self.camera.arm("SingleFrame")
            
    def capture_single(self):
        for i in range(10):
            try:
                frame = self.camera.acquire_frame()
                print(frame)

            except VimbaException as e:
                # rearm camera upon frame timeout
                if e.error_code == VimbaException.ERR_TIMEOUT:
                    print(e)
                    self.camera.disarm()
                    self.camera.arm('SingleFrame')
                else:
                    raise
        # Note: Not sure if you actually want to disarm the camera upon calling capture_single.
        # Perhaps make another method within the class, i.e. def disarm(self) that does this.
        self.camera.disarm()
        self.camera.close()
        return frame
```

Then, you could use

```
camera = CameraInteractor()
for i in range(10):
    frame = camera.capture_single()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the discussion, you might find this GitHub issue about manually managing the context of the camera object helpful. The camera is usually opened inside of the scope of the with statement and shouldn't be called outside of it. To change that up, you need to manually manage what the API usually does in the background with the with statement.
[Manually managing Instance and Camera contexts #116](https://github.com/alliedvision/VimbaPython/issues/116)

Edit: I didn't see how old this topic is at first. But maybe this does help someone.